# Programmatically Copying CSS Class properties over to a new Class

Tags: jquery, html, css

#### The Problem

I'm creating a small app for a website. This app includes a form with validation, but I've been having errors. Some of the built in styles I needed to maintain the same theme have some jQuery scripts interfering, and causing errors. This prevents my jQuery from working, and stops my form validation.

Note: I can't remove their jQuery script, it has to be in my view

#### Possible Solution

While I could look through the browser's inspector and copy the styles over, I'd rather learn a way to copy the class's properties over into another class, one that the website's jQuery script isn't looking for, thus avoiding the error and keeping the style intact.

#### Question

How can I take a CSS class, and programmatically assign its properties to a brand new class.

Best,

Jacob

Comment: I appreciate the question and it is actually quite interesting, but on SO usually it is best to show what you have already tried and/or researched on this. Have you found anything similar (but not perfect) or tried something yourself (again that isn't perfect or has errors)?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [plugin](https://github.com/moagrius/copycss)

Basic usage:

```
$('#some-element').copyCSS('#another-element');  // copy all styles
$('#some-element').copyCSS('#another-element', ['top', 'left']);  // copy just top and left
$('#some-element').copyCSS('#another-element', null, ['top', 'left']);  // copy everything except top and left
```